# OpenQuery inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, mdx, openquery

I have an OpenQuery that works only outside the stored procedure.

This works:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OpenQuery(LINKED_OLAP,
               'SELECT [Measures].[Sales] on columns FROM [Volumes] WHERE ([Calendar].[Day].&[' + convert(nvarchar(4),@Date,120) + ']&[' + DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) + ']&[' + RIGHT((convert(nvarchar(10),@Date,120)),2) + ']')
```

When I put this inside a stored procedure, and then execute the stored procedure, I get the error:

> Cannot process the object "SELECT * FROM OpenQuery(LINKED_OLAP,'SELECT [Measures].[Sales] on columns FROM [Volumes]')". The OLE DB provider "MSOLAP.5" for linked server "LINKED_OLAP" indicates that either the object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object.

I have permissions and there are columns in there. The query runs outside stored procedure, why doesn't it work when I call the stored procedure? I tried removing the `datename` function and the stored procedure worked. How can I fix this? I need this function to run.

Comment: related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64947/using-openquery-to-execute-a-script#64971

Comment: @dfundako thanks for the comment. I followed the proposed solution from the url you posted, but I get the exact same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out how to solve it.

Instead of using the DATENAME function, I passed it to a variable:

```
declare @TheMonth NVARCHAR(10) = DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE())
```